# How do I let my users insert a date in a specific format?

Tags: php, date

In an internal CMS/Order System we have a 'deadline' input field. Currently this is just a plain text and stored as such in the database (varchar). I want to change this since I can't *work* with this data in any way. The input should be that of a date (day-month-year).

What is the best way to do this? The solutions I came up with:

1. Use HTML5's `<input type="date" />`. This could work since we only use modern browsers internally.
2. jQuery datepicker. I havent really worked with jQuery before but I think this is a solid soluton.
3. Let users do whatever they want and use `strtotime()`?

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: Simple: 3. Even if you use jQuery AND HTML5's features users will still be able to do whatever the f they want.

Comment: as i know you datepicker is good to use because you can change date formar as you want.

Comment: You could also "pre-load" the field with e.g. todays date in the right format. This way people don't have to type it in unless the date is different and they are reminded about the correct format.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink I use HTML's `placeholder=""` atm. It doesn't work. You can't trust users :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use jquery date picker because its more userfriendly and keeping the datepicker readonly there is no need of further validation for date.Also you can change the desired format of date.

For reference check these links

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Comment: Thank you. I went with the jQuery approach.

Answer (score 1):

My simple suggestion is,

You can give a label text like **Note: Date format should be "dd-mm-yyyy"** below the text box.

Then you can validate the input format in Javascript & PHP. There are so many validation scripts available.

(or)

Use **Datepicker** for user friendly.